# String decode: looking for a better approach

Tags: c++, string

I have worked out a O(n square) solution to the problem. I was wondering about a better solution to this. (this is not a homework/interview problem but something I do out of my own interest, hence sharing here):

```
If a=1, b=2, c=3,….z=26. Given a string, find all possible codes that string
can generate. example: "1123" shall give:
aabc //a = 1, a = 1, b = 2, c = 3
kbc // since k is 11, b = 2, c= 3
alc // a = 1, l = 12, c = 3
aaw // a= 1, a =1, w= 23
kw // k = 11, w = 23
```

Here is my code to the problem:

```
void alpha(int* a, int sz, vector<vector<int>>& strings) {
    for (int i = sz - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i == sz - 1) {
            vector<int> t;
            t.push_back(a[i]);
            strings.push_back(t);
        } else {
            int k = strings.size();

            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
                vector<int> t = strings[j];
                strings[j].insert(strings[j].begin(), a[i]);

                if (t[0] < 10) {
                   int n = a[i] * 10 + t[0];

                    if (n <= 26) {
                        t[0] = n;
                        strings.push_back(t);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially the vector strings will hold the sets of numbers.
This would run in n square. I am trying my head around at least an nlogn solution.

Intuitively tree should help here, but not getting anywhere post that.

Comment: Having a working code and looking for improvements might be a candidate for codereview.stackexchange.com (though it's not to bad here either)

Comment: The speed problem in your code is not the O(n^2), but the tremendous amount of dynamic allocation.

Comment: The naming of your variables could use some improvement.  `vector<vector<int>> strings`?. `i, a, t, k` isn't really informative either.

Comment: Theoretically, you cannot get better than O(n^2) since the string `"1"^n` has O(n^2) solutions. In practice however, you will get close to linear time because every digit larger than 2 can be uniquely decoded (when processing the string from front to back). Just if you encounter a 1 (or 2), it could be either `a` or `10 + next digit`.

Comment: Best algorithm is a thing, but performances are more about memory management / cache miss. For example, create a vector every loop is going to put your performances in trouble.

Comment: @GameOfChess if you put some information about your code (your variables are horrible). I'll do a little clean to improve that.

Comment: Yes, I could have pulled out the vectors from the loop. 
Ideally I would have mapped the numbers (like 23 = w) in the loop itself and instead of vectors of vector, would have maintained a vector of strings.

Comment: if 1123 is the input, then: 1,1,2,3; 11,2,3; 1,12,3; 1,2,23; 11,23 would be the output if the 2 digit number is less than 26 (i.e. an english alphabet).
I am simply starting from end and in one vector combining it to previous number (23), in the other vector keeping it independent of this number(2,3) and then pushing both vectors in strings vector. Such vectors are getting updated every step of the loop.

Comment: I have figured out a tree approach as well:
1.) Hold an array and string in a node of binary tree.
2.) In one step resolve first element of array to a letter and concatenate it to the string. Create a left node with this new string and array-this used number. 
3.) In same step create right node by combining 1st 2 elements of array and resolve to an alphabet. 
4.) repeat 2 and 3 for left and right thus created
5.) In the end all the leaf nodes shall have the desired strings. 

I wonder if this shall have a time complexity O(n) and space O(n square)

Comment: You have a logical error, since your code starts at 1 and ends at 26 but you compare `if (n < 26)`. Result for code `a[] = {2, 6}` will be wrong.

Comment: @grek40 yeah correct.

Comment: @GameOfChess I wasn't able to understand the meaning of the variable in fact. Sorry I won't be able to cleanup this myself, but there are some tips: stop use std::vector when you can just represent the data in one int, you should use one std::vector<int>, and use something like -1 for separate each groups. I think your first if else may be removable (limit branch condition as many as possible). And one little thing, use ++i when you don't need i++ (okay that one won't change that much). Good luck

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel show me the seriously utilized compiler that doesn't optimize a freestanding integer `i++` to the same instruction as `++i` as soon as minimal optimization is enabled.

Comment: @grek40 that's why that one won't change that much like I said. Just a good thing to learn the difference between them. Seems like a lot of beginners don't even bother with the meanings of that they write and I think that's sad.

Comment: Another one on the `1..26` range: better make it `0..25` else you have to handle `10` and `20` specially, only accepting them as pair, not as individual digits (since `0` would be out of range)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, your problem complexity is more like `2^n`, not `n^2`, since your `k` can increase with every iteration.

This is an alternative recursive solution (note: recursion is bad for very long codes). I didn't focus on optimization, since I'm not up to date with C++X, but I think the recursive solution could be optimized with some `move`s.

Recursion also makes the complexity a bit more obvious compared to the iterative solution.

```
// Add the front element to each trailing code sequence. Create a new sequence if none exists
void update_helper(int front, std::vector<std::deque<int>>& intermediate)
{
    if (intermediate.empty())
    {
        intermediate.push_back(std::deque<int>());
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < intermediate.size(); i++)
    {
        intermediate[i].push_front(front);
    }
}

std::vector<std::deque<int>> decode(int digits[], int count)
{
    if (count <= 0)
    {
        return std::vector<std::deque<int>>();
    }

    std::vector<std::deque<int>> result1 = decode(digits + 1, count - 1);
    update_helper(*digits, result1);

    if (count > 1 && (digits[0] * 10 + digits[1]) <= 26)
    {
        std::vector<std::deque<int>> result2 = decode(digits + 2, count - 2);

        update_helper(digits[0] * 10 + digits[1], result2);

        result1.insert(result1.end(), result2.begin(), result2.end());
    }

    return result1;
}
```

Call:

```
std::vector<std::deque<int>> strings = decode(codes, size);
```

**Edit:**

Regarding the complexity of the original code, I'll try to show what would happen in the worst case scenario, where the code sequence consists only of `1` and `2` values.

```
void alpha(int* a, int sz, vector<vector<int>>& strings)
{
    for (int i = sz - 1;
        i >= 0;
        i--)
    {
        if (i == sz - 1)
        {
            vector<int> t;
            t.push_back(a[i]);
            strings.push_back(t); // strings.size+1
        } // if summary: O(1), ignoring capacity change, strings.size+1
        else
        {
            int k = strings.size();

            for (int j = 0; j < k; j++)
            {
                vector<int> t = strings[j]; // O(strings[j].size) vector copy operation

                strings[j].insert(strings[j].begin(), a[i]); // strings[j].size+1
                // note: strings[j].insert treated as O(1) because other containers could do better than vector

                if (t[0] < 10)
                {
                    int n = a[i] * 10 + t[0];

                    if (n <= 26)
                    {
                        t[0] = n;
                        strings.push_back(t); // strings.size+1
                        // O(1), ignoring capacity change and copy operation

                    } // if summary: O(1), strings.size+1

                } // if summary: O(1), ignoring capacity change, strings.size+1

            } // for summary: O(k * strings[j].size), strings.size+k, strings[j].size+1

        } // else summary: O(k * strings[j].size), strings.size+k, strings[j].size+1

    } // for summary: O(sum[i from 1 to sz] of (k * strings[j].size))
    // k (same as string.size) doubles each iteration => k ends near 2^sz
    // string[j].size increases by 1 each iteration
    // k * strings[j].size increases by ?? each iteration (its getting huge)
}
```

Maybe I made a mistake somewhere and if we want to play nice we can treat a vector copy as `O(1)` instead of `O(n)` in order to reduce complexity, but the hard fact remains, that the worst case is doubling outer vector size in each iteration (at least every 2nd iteration, considering the exact structure of the `if` conditions) of the inner loop and the inner loop depends on that growing vector size, which makes the whole story at least O(2^n).

**Edit2:**

I figured out the result complexity (the best hypothetical algoritm still needs to create every element of the result, so result complexity is like a lower bound to what any algorithm can archieve)

Its actually following the Fibonacci numbers:

For worst case input (like only `1`s) of `size N+2` you have:

- `size N` has `k(N)` elements
- `size N+1` has `k(N+1)` elements
- `size N+2` is the combination of codes starting with `a` followed by the combinations from `size N+1` (`a` takes one element of the source) and the codes starting with `k`, followed by the combinations from `size N` (`k` takes two elements of the source)
- `size N+2` has `k(N) + k(N+1)` elements

Starting with `size 1 => 1 (a)` and `size 2 => 2 (aa or k)`

Result: still exponential growth ;)

**Edit3:**

Worked out a dynamic programming solution, somewhat similar to your approach with reverse iteration over the code array and kindof optimized in its vector usage, based on the properties explained in Edit2.

The inner loop (`update_helper`) is still dominated by the count of results (worst case Fibonacci) and a few outer loop iterations will have a decent count of sub-results, but at least the sub-results are reduced to a pointer to some intermediate node, so copying should be pretty efficient. As a little bonus, I switched the result from numbers to characters.

Another edit: updated code with range `0 - 25` as `'a' - 'z'`, fixed some errors that led to wrong results.

```
struct const_node
{
    const_node(char content, const_node* next)
        : next(next), content(content)
    {
    }

    const_node* const next;
    const char content;
};

// put front in front of each existing sub-result
void update_helper(int front, std::vector<const_node*>& intermediate)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < intermediate.size(); i++)
    {
        intermediate[i] = new const_node(front + 'a', intermediate[i]);
    }
    if (intermediate.empty())
    {
        intermediate.push_back(new const_node(front + 'a', NULL));
    }
}

std::vector<const_node*> decode_it(int digits[9], size_t count)
{
    int current = 0;
    std::vector<const_node*> intermediates[3];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        current = (current + 1) % 3;
        int prev = (current + 2) % 3; // -1
        int prevprev = (current + 1) % 3; // -2

        size_t index = count - i - 1; // invert direction

        // copy from prev
        intermediates[current] = intermediates[prev];
        // update current (part 1)
        update_helper(digits[index], intermediates[current]);

        if (index + 1 < count && digits[index] &&
            digits[index] * 10 + digits[index + 1] < 26)
        {
            // update prevprev
            update_helper(digits[index] * 10 + digits[index + 1], intermediates[prevprev]);
            // add to current (part 2)
            intermediates[current].insert(intermediates[current].end(), intermediates[prevprev].begin(), intermediates[prevprev].end());
        }
    }
    return intermediates[current];
}

void cleanupDelete(std::vector<const_node*>& nodes);

int main()
{
    int code[] = { 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 };
    int size = sizeof(code) / sizeof(int);
    std::vector<const_node*> result = decode_it(code, size);

    // output
    for (size_t i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout.width(3);
        std::cout.flags(std::ios::right);
        std::cout << i << ": ";
        const_node* item = result[i];
        while (item)
        {
            std::cout << item->content;
            item = item->next;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    cleanupDelete(result);
}


void fillCleanup(const_node* n, std::set<const_node*>& all_nodes)
{
    if (n)
    {
        all_nodes.insert(n);
        fillCleanup(n->next, all_nodes);
    }
}

void cleanupDelete(std::vector<const_node*>& nodes)
{
    // this is like multiple inverse trees, hard to delete correctly, since multiple next pointers refer to the same target
    std::set<const_node*> all_nodes;
    for each (auto var in nodes)
    {
        fillCleanup(var, all_nodes);
    }
    nodes.clear();
    for each (auto var in all_nodes)
    {
        delete var;
    }
    all_nodes.clear();
}
```

A drawback of the dynamically reused structure is the cleanup, since you wanna be careful to delete each node only once.

Comment: the inner loop in my code runs on the size of vector (k) that changes indeed, but would grow from 2 to 2n in steps of 2. So, complexity would be 
2+4+...+2n = O(n^2)

Comment: @GameOfChess I'll re-check where you hid the complexity, but generally speaking, a code of `1,1,1,1,1,...` would produce a result of many `{a, k}` permutation with up to n `a`s or up to n/2 `k`s so as far as I can tell, the result space complexity is 2^n, so the creation can't possibly be n^2. As said, I'll re-check.

Comment: @GameOfChess hope my edit makes it clearer. The vector size is not limited to 2n.